# Jackson JSR-310 module fails to deserialize simplest OffsetDateTime format

Tags: json, datetime, jackson, java-8, deserialization

```
@Test
public void testJacksonOffsetDateTimeDeserializer() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    String json = "\"2015-10-20T11:00:00-8:30\"";

    mapper.readValue(json, OffsetDateTime.class); // boom!
}

java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2015-10-20T11:00:00-8:30' could not be parsed at index 19
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
```

Using version 2.6.3

Doesn't help even if I disable `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`, `DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE` and enable `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID`.

Apparently it really wants INSTANT format like 2015-10-20T11:00:00Z, without the time zone. Which for OffsetDateTime is kinda useless because the whole point is to use a time zone (or offset).

Any ideas?

Full disclosure: I've an [issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310/issues/48) open on their Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with a missing zero for the offset, that is `8:30` instead of `08:30`. Apparently `DateTimeFormatter#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` is very strict about it. I checked using all 3 `java.time.format.ResolverStyle` and none worked when the leading zero was missing. You'd think that `ResolverStyle.LENIENT` or `ResolverStyle.SMART` would work while `ResolverStyle.STRICT` might fail, but nops.

Thanks to the guys on Jackson dev team.